How to Looping the list of table contain business key pass to method to execute data process?
We are doing the data validation to pass the source table for SQL view names like TEST_SCH.VIEWNAME and target datalake delta view for schema.deltaview to compare the column row count testing. So that we have to write many scripts to execute.
I have common scripts in which I have to master the source and target table to pass the single scripts - then my script should execute all the source and target views. In both views, we are passing a common business key to sort the final compared data to confirm there is no difference in the data.
Below are scripts currently we are using but make it optimized and a single script to pass the list of source and target view name with business column details.
Sample current scripts for us now:
%run "/SQLSERVER/TEST_ConnectionInfo"

table_name = "[TEST].[SQL_TABLE_VIEW]"
source = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("databaseName", database_name) \
        .option("accessToken", access_token) \
        .option("encrypt", "true") \
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
        .load()
source.createOrReplaceTempView("source_view")

df = spark.sql(f"""select * from target.deltatableviewname""")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("target")

Source=spark.sql('select * from source_view')
Target=spark.sql('select * from target')

The first level of check source and target count should match our scripts.
Below one A-B and B-A concept with source-target data operation :
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_DataFromsrcDiff=Source.subtract(target).withColumn("Source", lit("A"))
df_DataFromtargetDiff=target.subtract(Source).withColumn("Target", lit("B"))

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
difference=df_DataFromtargetDiff.union(df_DataFromsrcDiff)
difference=diffdatadf.sort(col("businesskey for column"))

print(difference.count()) -- should give 0 count

The final result will be 0 only, if 0 there is no difference in both view data comparisons.
How should we achieve the list of views and business key pass to a single script to perform the data validation?
Kindly provide a solution to a single script to perform the above code to manipulate my data validation. Make sure each view we have to pass one or many business keys to sort in the final data difference approach, so please help us.
